# Are electric lines of force discontinuous?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields

In my text book it is written that

> "Every line of force in an electrostatic field originates from a positive charge at one end and terminates on a negative charge at other and they are discontinuous curves. A line of force start from a positive charge at a point A and ends at a negative charge at point B, on reaching B this line doesn't return to point A but in case of magnet it is not show".

This was written for a conductor which was mentioned later in the text. So my doubt was are the lines of force also discontinuous in case if we use a bar with two oppositely charged ends made of insulator i.e will they be continuous?

Comment: Could you quote the related text, please.

Comment: @user150960 Your question seems very unclear. I can't understand head or tail of it. Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question. If necessary, quote from the text, or provide images to explain what you mean.

Comment: Every line of force in an electrostatic field originates from a positive charge at one end and terminates on a negative charge at other and they are discontinuous curves .a line of force start from a positive charge at a point A and ends at a negative charge at point B ,on reaching B this line doesn't return to point A but in case of magnet it is not show

Comment: The lines of force will start at the positive side, and end at the negative side.

Comment: Just to be clear, is the original text in English, or have you a translation in your post? It's not in English, right?

Comment: What textbook is this? Is this a direct textual quote?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the book is just being pedantic about the notion that starting and ending represent dicontinuities in and of themselves.

The line ends at a negative charge rather than continuing beyond it and it started on a positive charge with no previous segment feeding into that point. So there are breaks in the flow at those charges.

It does not mean that the line of force exhibits dicontinuities between the starting and ending and ending charges.